# Don't allow null values in Collector for ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-online, arcgis-collector

I have created a geodatabase in ArcMap with four Feature Classes for a Survey using Collector for ArcGIS.

I have multiple Fields per Feature Class and various Domains for single and multiple use in the Feature Classes. Some fields in the Feature Classes should not allow null Values. This is correctly implemented in the different Feature classes. As well after loading the Layers to ArcGIS online the don't allow null values seems to work.

If I now publish the Service and use it with Collector for ArcGIS it does not work any more. Which means, I can collect new data without an error if the fields contain nulls. 
Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have been waiting for this functionality also.  As far as I am aware this is still in development and so far is not actually possible to implement in Collector.  There are a number of workarounds suggested, including this at the foot of the page, which I am yet to test. [AGOL Layer Definition edit](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/122174)